# Can't connect (using Putty) to local virtual machine

Tags: networking, ssh, putty, vmware

I have created an Ubuntu server on VMWare player with a Bridged connection. I am able to web to it and SSH to it on another computer or even another local VM. Though I am unable to both web to it and SSH to it on my local machine and only able to ping it. I am able to web and SSH to other machines on my network. Also tried to do a reinstall, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please do the network settings as below.
Then after login through putty ,enter your user login for VM